# JupyterLab application assets not found

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I just downloaded jupyter lab using pip on my macbook. When I run jupyter lab on my terminal, browser opens with the following error:

> JupyterLab Error JupyterLab application assets not found in
> "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab"
> Please run `jupyter lab build` or use a different app directory

I can run jupyter notebook with no problem.

Note: I can use jupyter lab by running `jupyter lab --code-mode`

Comment: Do you also use pyenv?

Comment: No, I don't use pyenv, didn't install it.

Comment: I had a similar issue. The problem was that jupyter was configured with an non-existent virtual environment. Compare the output of `jupyter --paths` with the location of your current Python interpreter `which python3`. You probably see that the paths under "config" differ from the location of your interpreter.

Comment: I believe that was the reason. Now that I use conda for environment management, I don't have that problem anymore. Both python3 and jupyter paths are in anaconda folder. Thank you for explaning the reason

Answer (score 27):

This issue can be resolved by manually set the application directory: `jupyter lab --app-dir /opt/homebrew/share/jupyter/lab`, replace `/opt/homebrew` with the actual homebrew path.

Encountered this issue when installing `jupyterlab` with pip3.

Comment: How to permanently fix this? I.e. setting for app-dir

Comment: How do I work out what the correct path should be? (I also got this error when installing with pip3).

Comment: Here is permanently fixing solution. Run`jupyter lab --generate-config`. Then config file is created with printing location of the file(eg. `Writing default config to: /Users/blabla/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py`). Open the config file and modify content into `c.LabApp.app_dir = '/opt/homebrew/share/jupyter/lab'`. That's all. @LukaBradeško

Comment: On Linux/linuxbrew (Homebrew 4.1.16) was `jupyter lab --app-dir /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/jupyter/lab`

Comment: What about for WSL2? My path in the error is this: /home/bexgboost/.local/share/jupyter/lab

Comment: I ran `jupyter lab build` to get the path before writing in the config. 
Without doing this, extensions were not getting installed. Hope this helps someone in the future to save time.

Answer (score -1):

Please run `conda install jupyterlab` instead. I tried this on with miniforge (https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh) and it worked.

Comment: I don't have any expertise here, so I can't speak to why this answer was downvoted, but this was the only thing that fixed it for me, so- thanks!