# Can't use Jupyter Notebook because of "missing or misshapen translation settings schema"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, terminal, jupyter, homebrew

I have assignments in school where I'm supposed to use Jupyter Notebook by running it from the terminal, hosting it locally. The first time I did it, it went fine until I tried quitting it on the browser, where nothing happened, so I just closed the browser and the terminal window. Since then, I'm getting the error as written in the title "Missing or misshapen translation settings schema".

I've googled and looked at solutions, tried them without any luck. Most talk about Anaconda and other stuff that they've had to uninstall and update, but I don't use those anyway. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645842/jupyterlab-application-assets-not-found) which I thought might work, but it didn't unfortunately.

The error is:

```
[W 2023-08-30 20:55:30.861 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2023-08-30 20:55:30.861 JupyterNotebookApp] Settings directory does not exist at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas
[W 2023-08-30 20:55:30.908 JupyterNotebookApp] Missing or misshapen translation settings schema:
    HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/translation-extension/plugin.json)
[W 2023-08-30 20:55:30.908 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyter-notebook/application-extension:shell?1693421730904 (::1): Schema not found: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyter-notebook/application-extension/shell.json
```

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this exact same error when I updated Jupyter Notebook through pip in MacOS recently. I am not sure really what exactly happened but it seems like something got corrupted in the installation and env.

I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6974#issuecomment-1675394990) with a solution that worked for me to solve this error (and apparently also worked for a lot more other people)

Basically reinstalling `jupyterlab` (regardless if you use Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook Classic)

```
pip3 uninstall jupyterlab
pip3 install jupyterlab
jupyter lab build
jupyter lab
jupyter notebook
```

In the Github thread comment they install an specific version of jupyterlab (3.6.3), this was not needed in my case as I installed the latest.

Comment: Bless you, my good man. That worked!

Comment: This worked. Thanks!